# brew python3 suddenly stopped working on MacOs

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos

I had `python` (which was python2) and `python3` both installed on my Mac OS High Sierra. I was doing some installations in which I ran:

```
brew install automake
brew install doxygen
brew install ant
```

and during these processes, my brew must have been updated as well. And now, I realised that `python3`, which has been perfectly working for the last few months, just vanished.

```
> brew update
Already up-to-date.

> brew install python
Error: python 2.7.14 is already installed
To upgrade to 3.6.4_4, run `brew upgrade python`

> brew install python3
Error: python 2.7.14 is already installed
To upgrade to 3.6.4_4, run `brew upgrade python`
```

And now, I do not seem to be able to reinstall `python3` back. What's, more, I am afraid that if I run `brew upgrade python`, I will lose access to python2.

**PS**: I've noticed the absence of `python3` when I opened my terminal and it said:

```
Last login: Sat Mar 10 15:16:43 on ttys002
virtualenvwrapper_run_hook:12: no such file or directory: /usr/local/bin/python3
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks.

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python3 and that PATH is
set properly.
```

Any ideas on how to fix this or what might have been the cause of the problem?

Comment: anything interesting from `brew doctor`?

Comment: @meatspace I am not completely sure if I understand it properly. Here is its output: https://hastebin.com/imeyuvozen.sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case someone else is having the same problem, `brew upgrade python` does not break anything. I ran it and I still have access to Python 2 and additionally, I got Python 3. Also, all old libraries remain pre-installed

Answer (score 1):

The reason is explained here: https://brew.sh/2018/01/19/homebrew-1.5.0/

I would suggest to add the new formula: `brew install python@2`

Running `brew info python@2` you will get the location of the package installed:

/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.14_3

Keep in mind that python@2 is a "keg-only" formula, which means that it's not linked into */usr/local*. At this point, depending on your needs you should force a link to it if necessary. Try first a `--dry-run` to understand what will happen:

```
brew link --force --dry-run python@2
```

If you do not want to run the brew link command, you always create a convenient symbolic link (you will have to keep the link updated in case you run an update of the formula):

```
ln -s ../Cellar/python@2/2.7.14_3/bin/python python2
```

Bottom line is that homebrew started considering python2 obsolete.